# using SendMessage from user32.dll with jna in java - error

Tags: java, winapi, jna, sendmessage, user32

I try to use the:

```
LRESULT WINAPI SendMessage(_In_  HWND hWnd, _In_  UINT Msg,
                           _In_  WPARAM wParam, _In_  LPARAM lParam);
```

in Java with jna and i keep getting a error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'SendMessage'
```

this is my interface:

```
public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
Pointer GetForegroundWindow();
int SendMessage(Pointer hWnd, int msg, int num1, int num2);
```

and i call it like that:

```
Pointer hW = user32.GetForegroundWindow();
user32.SendMessage(hW, 0x0201, 0, 0);
user32.SendMessage(hW, 0x0202, 0, 0);
```

the hWnd is right. where is my mistake?

Comment: Are you using Java 32bit or 64 bit version?

Comment: I think i have both installed - how can i check?

Comment: How do you run the program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JNA can not find the function "SendMessage" in user32.dll because there no function of that name exported.

This is because SendMessage is an old name that is automatically mapped by the other compilers to the matching ANSI or UNICODE version of the function - `SendMessageA` and `SendMessageW`.

Using tools that show the exported functions of a DLL like DependencyWalker you can see that user32.dll of Windows 7 for example only knows both functions `SendMessageA` and `SendMessageW` but no `SendMessage`.

The function definition you use looks like the ANSI version, hence you should use `SendMessageA` instead.

BTW. It doesn't make any difference if you are using 32bit or 64bit Java and user32.dll. What I wrote is true for both versions.

Comment: ah thank you!! it works...  but it always clicks 0,0 i think the position is send with the lParam value. What's the right format for it?

Comment: 0x0201 is WM_LBUTTONDOWN therefore you find the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: no i meant the position of the click - as you can see i already had the right value for the 'clickevent'

Comment: Please look at the lParam documentation of WM_LBUTTONDOWN. Its behind the link I posted.

Comment: it's waiting for a word parameter that can be made with: WORD MAKEWORD(
  BYTE bLow,
  BYTE bHigh
); but how do i do that in java?

Comment: You are wrong, not MAKEWORD, MAKEDWORD with takes two WORD not BYTE. You can compute it using basic math using [binary operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) `dword = wLow | (wHigh << 16)` This works as long as x and y are positive numbers.